# C# Which thread pattern to choose

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, block

Say we have an interface method A, which is reentrant capable and for every entry in the method the current thread shall wait until an event occurs specifically for **this** thread:

```
void interfaceMethodA()
{
    doSomething();
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
}
```

Now, there will be set()-calls for the waitHandle, so that the method will be exited. But those set() calls must release a **specific** thread of the (possible) thread queue and not neccessarily the first one. What is a best practise for this pattern, maybe wait() and pulse() in combination with a thread id vector? To me this seems a bit like a mess...

Thanks in advance, Juergen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `ThreadLocal<WaitHandle>`

```
ThreadLocal<WaitHandle> waitHandle = new ThreadLocal<WaitHandle>(() => new ManualResetEvent(false));

void interfaceMethodA()
{
    doSomething();
    waitHandle.Value.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look on this, it's new to me.

Comment: @Juergen, it's new to the framework as well. You'll need 4.0 to use it.